# How to insert data to table based on a specific condition

Tags: javascript, sql, sqlite, insert

I have 3 tables: `TimeTable`, `Subject`, `WeekDay`.

The `TimeTable` table has the following fields: `SubjectId`, `WeekDayId`.

I want to insert values into the `TimeTable` table, but the data comes in names, not `id.s`, so I want to execute this statement:

```
Insert into TimeTable SubjectId , WeekDayId 
Select WeekDay.WeekdayId , Subject.SubjectId from weekday , Subject 
Where Subject.SubjectName=IPSubjectName And Weekday.WeekDayName=IPWeekDayName
```

Now I have 2 questions:

1. Is this statement available in sqlite (Am I writing it right)?
2. How can I dynamically take input at these values (IPSubjectName, IPWeekDayName).
   i.e If I have var SubjectName, var WeekDayName, how will the statement be written then?

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes, I think the statement you wrote is available in SQLite.
2. I'm assuming you wrote a PHP function which calls this query, in which case, your variable names would become `$SubjectName` and `$WeekDayName`. Then, your code will become:

   ```
   Where Subject.SubjectName=$SubjectName AND Weekday.WeekDayName=$WeekDayName
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the values as parameters in the function where you are executing the query and replay the right hand side clause with `${paramname1}` and `${paramname2}`.